# Are (Galois) conjugates of points in general position also in general position?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, galois-theory

$\newcommand\Q{\mathbb Q} \newcommand\R{\mathbb R} \newcommand\P{\mathbb P}$Let $K$ be a Galois field extension of $\Q$. Define $L:=K\cap \R$ and suppose that there are three distinct points $P_1,P_2,P_3 \in \P^2(L)$ that are not collinear. Is it true that the set of points
$$X:=\bigcup_{i=1}^3\{\sigma(P_i):\sigma\in\mathrm{Gal}(K/\Q) \} $$
are in general position in $\P^2(K)$? For what conditions of $P_1,P_2,P_3\in \P^2(L)$ can we conclude that the above generated set consists of points in general position in $\P^2(K)$? I think I can reduce the question to the affine plane as well.

Actually I don't even know this for just quadratic field extensions $K$ (for a moment I could care less about the field not being real). My aim is to determine the minimum degree in the vanishing ideal of $X$.

Comment: A simple example where this may not hold, disregarding conditions for $K$, is the following: $P_1=(1,1), P_2=(\sqrt 2, 1), P_3=(7,7)$ in $K=\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2)$. Then there are four points after taking conjugates and $3$ of them are colinear. I don't think the condition for $K$ (i.e. non-real  and Galois) will hinder us from making such counterexamples.